# Tensorflow checkpoint errors caused by protobuf

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm facing an error when running tensorflow model (bert) on Ubuntu.

Error message is as follows:

> [libprotobuf FATAL external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/map.h:1064] CHECK failed: it != end(): key not found: architecture
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>     what():  CHECK failed: it != end(): key not found: architecture
>   Fatal Python error: Aborted

I'm using python 3.6.8, tensorflow 1.14.0 and the result of `pip3 show protobuf` says

Name: protobuf
Version: 3.9.1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /home/titan-n0/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, setuptools

The above error occurs right before making a checkpoint. I need this to make a saved model from tf serving.

Comment: Please provide a [repro]. Without one, it is often impossible to diagnose a problem.

Comment: minimal reproducible example would be.... running run_squad.py (tensorflow bert training model. The above mentioned error pops up everytime I run a model.